# XRDP- Reduce network egress on remote desktop

Tags: linux, cloud, remote-desktop, xfce, xrdp

I connect my old Windows laptop as a client to connect to a Cloud(Azure/GCP/Aws) based Linux VM for development work. On client side I use RDP and at remote VM I've configured XRDP. Cloud based VM seems a good cost effective option with greater flexibility to chose the specs like processor, memory, etc, however the problem is high Network Egress when doing remote desktop. The egress or 'Network Out' comes out to 20 MB/minute for regular development work like working on an IDE, browser, etc. If I connect to a Windows VM, I'm able to limit the Egress to 2MB/minute by following [Microsoft's guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/remote-desktop/session-hosts#remote-desktop-protocol-data-compression).

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth used by XRDP? 
Tried following but doesn't reduce Egress:

- Selected the Experience to low bandwidth on RDP settings.
- On the VM switched to a lightweight desktop environment XFCE.
- On the VM /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini, set max_bpp to 16.